# Strange behavior of \bibliographystyle{ieeetr} for inproceedings

Tags: bibtex, cite-package

I cannot figure out why the bibiographystule ieeetr (or IEEEtrans) is putting the city in parenthesis in the bibliography listing:

[image]

Here is the bibtex entry:

```
@InProceedings{McCarthy1993,
  Title                    = {Notes on formalizing context},
  Author                   = {McCarthy, J.},
  Booktitle                = {Proceedings of the 13th International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence},
  Year                     = {1993},

  Address                  = {San Mateo, California},
  Pages                    = {555-562},
  Publisher                = {Morgan Kaufmann},

  Owner                    = {rob},
  Timestamp                = {2015.07.10},
  Url                      = {http://bit.ly/OEHAyO}
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
\usepackage{cite}
...
\bibliography{_rg_refs}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

`\bibliographystyle{plain}` does not have this behavior.

Comment: This is specified by the bibliographystyle and so is by design.

Answer (score 1):

For entries of type `@inproceedings`, the bibliography style `ieeetr` provides the following definition of the function `inproceedings`:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.paddress output
      format.pages output
      organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

The key instruction in this code block, from the point of view of your query, is

```
      format.paddress output
```

which serves to format the publisher's address. The function `format.address`, in turn, is defined as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.paddress}
{ address empty$
    { "" }
    { "(" address * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

Observe the hard-coded opening and closing parentheses that are placed around the contents of the `address` field if the field is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Would you recommend that I just go and edit the source file for ieeetr, or would it be better to use \renewcommand?

Comment: @robguinness - For sure, you can't use `\renewcommand` (a LaTeX macro) since BibTeX's programming paradigm is *not* based on TeX. You should ask yourself, what are you trying to achieve? The `ieeetr` bibliography style has been around, pretty much unchanged, for well more than two decades. If you're required to use this style, you better not modify it unless you want to invite conflicts.

Comment: I'm trying to format references for my thesis. IEEEtr is pretty close to the style I want, but this parenthesis around the city seems pretty strange to me. I can't remember ever seeing an IEEE paper have citations formatted like that (I could be wrong though...)

Comment: @robguinness - You may want to look into using the `makebst` utility of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package to create your very own bespoke bibliography style. It's a menu-driven utility, with multiple-choice answers for every question. One of the very nice aspects of this utility is that there's no further need to compromise on any design elements: *You* decide every single formatting aspect.